# Redirect to error page if destination doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'd like to let the users access to non-existent or error pages to redirect somewhere.
If a user accesses `*application.com/somewhere*` and it doesn't exist, the user should be redirected to `*application.com/dashboard*`.

Do I have to make changes to config files or route.php?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. puts below code on route.php. that'll be redirect to URL/dashboard when any error happens.

**all of error redirect to URL/dashboard**

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
   Log::error($exception);

  if (Config::get('app.debug') == false) 
  {
    return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
  }
});
```

Comment: What `Config::get('app.debug')` returns?

Comment: #yannis  
At production the debub mode is going to be false for hide any error message and so. but your way is much simple. I'm gonna use it yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily handle this

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
});
```

http://laravel.com/docs/errors